# .NET 7 app developed from Arm64 won’t run on x64

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, windows-arm64

I’m developing a .NET 7 app on Windows 11, Arm64. Compiling for “any CPU”.
When trying to run the app in X64 computers, I get an error saying “This app can’t run on your PC”.
The computer has .NET 7 SDK and runtime installed.

If I compile the app using .NET Framework 4.8 on the Arm64 computer, it works properly on the x64 computer as well.
What is the issue with .NET 7 here?

Comment: Do you move the compiled .exe from computer to computer? If so, it seems that the .NET Runtime for .NET Core 7 is missing (or cannot be found) on the target computer, while the normal .NET Framework 4.8 is. Using AnyCPU should allow such interoperability.

Comment: You've got the wrong .net host, the .exe file.  It is an native .exe that takes care of locating the runtime, loading the CLR and just-in-time compiler and jitting your Main() entrypoint.  Being native, it can only run on an Arm processor.   You could arbitrarily copy the .exe file from another similar project that was built on an x64 machine and rename it.  Or run the app with dotnet.exe.  You only get true "AnyCPU" with dotnet.exe

Comment: Thank you Hans. I was able to start the application from the cmd.exe using >dotnet <path-to-app-DLL>. 
Why isn’t a universal app.exe being created when I compile? How can I create a universal exe?

Comment: Operating systems and processors are not universal.  This mattered back in the legacy framework as well, but they were *really* clever at hiding the issue.  It required patching the OS loader at runtime.  The kind of trick that doesn't port to the Unixes.

Comment: But obviously the application is executable on x64 using the dotnet.exe. So how do I create an exe on ARM that is executable directly on x64?

Comment: @maxo you can use [OS-specific TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms) to publish the app.

Comment: @GuruStron, it's all on Windows, so I'm already targeting Windows Framework. The difference is that I'm developing on Arm64, and targeting x64.

Comment: @maxo you can use architecture specific TFM, for example - `win-x64`

Comment: @GuruStron, thank you! That actually worked.. but it created an insane amount of DLLs in the release folder. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `dotnet` to run your compiled dll or publish the app (via the UI or using [`dotnet publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)) providing  architecture specific [runtime identifier (RID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids) for example - `win-x64`. Note the `--self-contained` parameter which by default is true when RID is specified and the project is an executable one:

> `--sc|--self-contained [true|false]`

> Publishes the .NET runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine. Default is `true` if a runtime identifier is specified and the project is an executable project (not a library project).

Which will lead to publishing all components of the app, including the .NET libraries and target runtime (see [the corresponding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)). Set it to `false` to publish framework-dependent executable, for example:

```bash
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

Also you can consider using [publish profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Thank you, this was my solution. The self-contained flag also removed all redundant libraries. But good to know that the option exist.

Comment: @maxo was glad to help! Self-contained usually pairs well with single file option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AnyCPU NET Core app that you want to build once and run on all platforms (x86/x64/ARM64), then you'll need 3 EXEs, one for each platform. There are 2 main problems with the way it currently behaves:

1. Long build times = Even though your app might target AnyCPU, which means you only have to build it once, adding runtime identifiers for each supported platform means you'll have to build and publish it once for each of those platforms.
2. The build output is not deterministic because it depends upon the platform of the build environment. When developer A gets the sources and builds the app on x64 machine, he'll get x64 EXE. Developer B takes the same sources, builds it on his ARM64 machine and he'll get ARM64-only EXE.

To address both issues, I tried to reverse-engineer the current build process and I came up with this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Do not generate the default app host which for Any CPU depends upon the OS where we build - x64 for x64 OS, ARM64 for ARM64 OS -->
    <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomAppHostBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Console app or Windows UI app? -->
        <CustomUseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface Condition="'$(OutputType)'=='WinExe'">true</CustomUseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface>
        <MyProgramFilesPath>$([System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%"))</MyProgramFilesPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CustomTargetPathx86>$(MyProgramFilesPath)\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x86</CustomTargetPathx86>
        <CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex86>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathx86)").Length), 1))</CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex86>
        <CustomTargetNetSdkx86>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathx86)")[$(CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex86)])</CustomTargetNetSdkx86>

        <CustomTargetPathx64>$(MyProgramFilesPath)\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64</CustomTargetPathx64>
        <CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex64>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathx64)").Length), 1))</CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex64>
        <CustomTargetNetSdkx64>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathx64)")[$(CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOnex64)])</CustomTargetNetSdkx64>

        <CustomTargetPathARM64>$(MyProgramFilesPath)\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-arm64</CustomTargetPathARM64>
        <CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOneARM64>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathARM64)").Length), 1))</CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOneARM64>
        <CustomTargetNetSdkARM64>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("$(CustomTargetPathARM64)")[$(CustomTargetDirectoriesLengthMinusOneARM64)])</CustomTargetNetSdkARM64>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <!-- Generate hosts per-platform: x64 will be the default app host no matter the OS where we build $(RuntimeFrameworkVersion) -->
    <CreateAppHost AppHostSourcePath="$(CustomTargetNetSdkx64)\runtimes\win-x64\native\apphost.exe" AppBinaryName="$(AssemblyName).dll" WindowsGraphicalUserInterface="$(CustomUseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface)" AppHostDestinationPath="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName).exe" IntermediateAssembly="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" />
    <CreateAppHost AppHostSourcePath="$(CustomTargetNetSdkx86)\runtimes\win-x86\native\apphost.exe" AppBinaryName="$(AssemblyName).dll" WindowsGraphicalUserInterface="$(CustomUseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface)" AppHostDestinationPath="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName)_x86.exe" IntermediateAssembly="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" />
    <CreateAppHost AppHostSourcePath="$(CustomTargetNetSdkARM64)\runtimes\win-arm64\native\apphost.exe" AppBinaryName="$(AssemblyName).dll" WindowsGraphicalUserInterface="$(CustomUseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface)" AppHostDestinationPath="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName)_ARM64.exe" IntermediateAssembly="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" />
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Include the generated hosts in the publish output -->
    <None Include="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName).exe">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <Visible>False</Visible>
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </None>
    <None Include="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName)_x86.exe">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <Visible>False</Visible>
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </None>
    <None Include="$(TargetDir)\$(AssemblyName)_ARM64.exe">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <Visible>False</Visible>
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

It creates all 3 hosts in the published output and it defaults to x64 as the main platform regardless of the build machine. Just add it to the csproj.

Working example can be found here: https://github.com/jimm98y/MultiTargetingSample

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Also, be careful about overtly promoting stuff you're affiliated with (I noticed every one of your answers contains a link to your GitHub). This could easily get your answers spam flagged and all of them deleted. People on Stack Overflow generally don't like unsolicited self-promotion. See [how to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: You're right, thank you for letting me know! I'll try to improve my answers in the future.